# Is it possible to alias a filename on an apache webserver?

Tags: apache, http, alias

I would like to make e.g. www.address.com/u.exe equal to www.address.com/serverfile.php or pl?

Is it possible?
So if someone types www.address.com/u.exe should get servefile.php...

Thanks for showing the right direction..

This seems to work. RewriteEngine on also had to be added.

I had to change .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^u\.exe$ serverfile.php
```

Comment: Do you want u.exe to appear in the address bar or serverfile.php?

Comment: Should this question goes to  serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with mod_rewrite like below.

```
RewriteRule ^/u.exe$ /serverfile.php [L]
```

Or below if you want to display serverfile.php (via a redirect).

```
RewriteRule ^/u.exe$ /serverfile.php [RL]
```

Comment: oh nevermind, i see you added RewriteEngine On -- i assumed that was implied :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's what the `mod_alias` Apache module does for you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Are you sure I can "alias" a filename using mod_alias? So far I can see this can be done through mod_rewrite only....

Comment: Yes, I am quite positive as this is how I have things set up on some sites I maintain. Even though the documentation doesn't say it, you can alias a file. For example: alias /u.exe /file/system/path/serverfile.php